# #REF! result when using INDEX function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I am trying to create a couple of reports from data on another Excel worksheet based on the value in a drop down list.  I am using the MATCH and INDEX functions and have created Named Ranges of the columns of data.  I am able to get the first value I want in the report but none of the others, even though when I debug by evaluating the formula it points to the right cell but still displays #REF! instead of the actual value from the referenced cell.

I'll do my best to make this clear:

- In "POST_Data" worksheet I have 4 columns titled Course Name, Course Length, Attendee and Date Attended.  Currently I have 33 rows of data (plus the header row) but I need the reports to be dynamic since new data will be added from time to time.
- I have created Dynamic Named Ranges of the data using the OFFSET function (e.g. for the Course Name data I have a NameRange called CourseNamesData = OFFSET(POST_Data!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(POST_Data!$A:$A),1)
- In the "DashBoard_and_Data Entry" worksheet I have a two report areas: one to report the Course Name and Date Attended for a specified Attendee (specified by a drop down list in cell C7) and the other report to provide the Attendee Name and Date Attended for a specified Course Name (specified by a drop down list in I7).
- In row 8 I report the column that the data belongs to in the POST_Data worksheet
- What IS working: When I choose an Attendee from the drop down list in C7, I correctly report the first of the Course Names for this attendee from the data in the POST_Data worksheet.  I used the following formula to do so: =INDEX(CourseNamesData,MATCH(C7,AttendeeNamesData,0),B$8)
- What is NOT working: The corresponding "Date Attended" data when I use a similar formula as the one that is working.  I have: =INDEX(DateAttendedData,MATCH(C7,AttendeeNamesData,0),C$8) but this gives me the #REF! error.

Again, when I try to follow the data that this formula points to, it looks like it is pointing to the correct cell but not showing the result.

Another issue is how to get all the data corresponding to the choice in the drop down and not just the first row.  So for example, if I choose Richards, K. from the attendee list and he has attended 4 training courses, I need all 4 to show up, not just the first one.

I appreciate any help or insights on this.  If you know of a better way to display the workbook contents, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to get the drop down to show all 4 items, you need to have an intermediate step in which you assign unique ids to all of the attendees in the attendee list. You can do this by using COUNTIF() to count the number of times that the attendee's name appears HIGHER on the list. Then your intermediate step would pull `ATTENDEE_NAME & #` for up to XXX number of events, and then your drop down shows all of the ones that were successful.

Comment: This question is not related to programming and should be posted to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a screenshot so that I can better understand the issue?

With regard to your post_data worksheet, you might find it easier to turn the data into a table. You can then point your named range to the column within the table without needing to use the offset function, and your range will update automatically as you add to the table.

I have a entire playlist on my youtube channel devoted to using ranges and tables if you are interested. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1nLTDk2QLL9415OPSjIICJs1EeV-HeK3